# Blocking vs Non Blocking Asynchronous code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I was doing a self review of some old code already written and was wondering if the following piece of code blocks current thread in any way or its non-blocking all the way?

As recommended by Microsoft, I use single HttpClient instance for all application

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

```
public virtual async Task<Tuple<string, bool>> PostAsync(string resourceUrl, string body, string basicToken)
{
    string methodName = "PostAsync";
    var response = new Tuple<string, bool>(string.Empty, false);
    try
    {
        var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, resourceUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", basicToken);
        request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var httpResponse = await ApplicationWrapper.AccessTokenClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response = new Tuple<string, bool>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false), httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Util.Log(methodName + " | WebException: " + e.Message + "|" + e.StackTrace.ToString());
        using (WebResponse WebResponse = e.Response)
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WebResponse;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(WebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                Util.Log(methodName + " | Exception postAsync API: " + streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Util.Log(methodName + " | Exception: " + ex.Message + "|" + ex.StackTrace.ToString() + "|" + ex.InnerException);
    }


    return response;
}
```

The fact that Microsoft states for ReadAsStringAsync

> This operation will not block. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=netframework-4.8

Also, in order to avoid deadlocks use of ConfigureAwait(false) is recommended

> ConfigureAwait(false) configures the task so that continued after the await does not have to be run in the caller context, therefore avoiding any possible deadlocks. https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f

**A blocking async code under stress can affect server with CPU Utilization touching to 90% as Number of  threads keep increasing ...**
Is there any aspect in the above code that is blocking?

Comment: `ReadToEnd` in the `catch` could be replaced by a `ReadToEndAsync` but I'd not worry too much about it. I'm not sure this question is a good fit for SO. It may be a better fit on Code Review.

Comment: There is no such thing as "blocking async code". If it's async, it's not blocking.

Comment: And there is no need to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` unless you are writing a library that will be used in projects by other people. It only prevents deadlocks when someone synchronously waits on your asynchronous code (e.g. Use `.Wait()` or `.Result` on a `Task`). If you're the only one calling your code, and you never do that, then `ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't needed.

Comment: what version of dotnet are you using? They changed recommendations on dotnet core 3

Comment: Using ASP.NET mvc 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This all looks good to me. An easy rule of thumb is if you see any occurrences of  `.Result` or `.Wait()` on the return value (`Task`) of an async method, you're blocking where you *probably* should be `await`ing. Not seeing that here - you appear to be awaiting all async calls. Now just make sure that anything *calling* this method is also `await`ing, all the way up the call stack. If you're blocking anywhere, it's all for naught. :)

Comment: Yes its awaiting all the way up the stack

Comment: @ToddMenirr .. when we are awaiting a method that does not block current thread right ? .. unless we use Result or wait

Comment: Correct. `await` basically instructs the compiler to rewrite the rest of the method as a callback that fires when the `Task` completes, freeing up the current thread.